# Django - How to auto populate form field from two others fields

Tags: django, forms, auto-populate

Here's what I'm looking for. In my form I have three fields, all CharFields. Those are Name, Surname and Username. Username should be set as a sum of Name and Surname, so for Name = Joe, Surname = Black, Username = Joe Black.

As the form is displayed, all fields all empty. I'd like it to auto-populate the Username while i'm writing data to a Name or a Surname. The reason of this is that I don't have to fill the Username field, but when I'd like to, I will be able to set it different than Name + Surname.

Is it possible without using jQuery? If so, is there any good tutorial on this?

Comment: If you want to do it on client-side you should use JavaScript, with or without jQuery.

Comment: That's what I was trying to ommit. I remember in some tutorial, I saw about a year ago, there was a way to auto-populate a SlugField, but I somehow can't find it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function updateUsername(){
        first = document.getElementById("first").value;
        last = document.getElementById("last").value;
        document.getElementById("username").value = first+" "+last;
    }

</script>
```

then you need to give your 3 input fields IDs.

Here's a example

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="" id="first" onkeyup="updateUsername();">
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="" id="last" onkeyup="updateUsername();">
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="" id="username">
```

Basically when the #first and #last field are typed into it runs the updateUsername() function which gets their values and changes the value of #username to them.

**EDIT**

If you want to do this with django, edit your model and overwrite the save method.

```
def save(self):
    if not self.id:
        self.username = self.first + self.last
    super(MODLE_NAME, self).save()
```

What that'll do is when you use the save() method, it'll take it's first and last properties and update the username value and save it.

Comment: Actually I've searched for a pure, django solution, with no js. But... this one is so simple, I can clearly give +1. If there won't be any better answer (without using js), I'll accept this one.

Comment: You can't do this without javascript. The closest other way to do this the django way, would be to save the model, then auto-generate the username from the first and last names. But that wouldn't give you a "live typing" feel to it.

Comment: I think, that's pretty all on this topic. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note, when overriding the `save` method, you should pass args like this: `save(self, *args, **kwargs)` and `super(MODEL_NAME, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.